# Change name of the named route in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a following `routes.rb`

```
resources :authors do
  resources :books, only: [:create, :read] do
    post "read"
  end
end
```

I would like to have the named route to be `read_authors_books`, but it gets generated as `authors_books_read`, is there a way to change the named route?

I have tried `post "read" as: :read_authors_books` but it generates it as `authors_books_read_authors_books`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `:read` as a `member_route`

```
resources :authors do
  resources :books, only: [:create] do
    post :read, on: :member
  end
end
```

This will generate

```
read_author_book POST   /authors/:author_id/books/:id/read(.:format) books#read
    author_books POST   /authors/:author_id/books(.:format)          books#create
```

Comment: I am getting `undefined local variable or method 'on'`

Comment: just copy the exact block as it is, I posted the result as well.

Comment: check if you missed the comma